# Methods for finding the minimum coordinate of an equation (any shortcuts?)

Tags: inequality, quadratics

**I want to know if there's a quicker method to find the minimum coordinates of a quadratic equation other than the one described below.**

Some background:

I was reviewing "Completing Squares and Inequalities" when I came to this inequality: $ y \leq x^2 - 2x +2$. This ends up being $(x-1)^2 + 1$

I now want to find the minimum coordinates of this expression. The vertex can be found with $\frac{-b}{2a}$ and my current rationale is the following:

*Premise I: $a > 0$, then this equation has a minimum*

*Premise II: Vertex can be found with $[\frac{-b}{2a}, f(\frac{-b}{2a})]$*

1. Find the vertex: $\frac{-b}{2a} = \frac{-(-2)}{2(1)} = \frac{2}{2} = 1$
2. Then replace that in the original equation:
   $(1)^2 - 2(1) +2 = 1 - 2 + 2 = 1$

Alternatively I can make use of the "Vertex form" $a(x - h)^2 + k$ and get that from the "completed square" $(x - 1)^2 + 1$ so we know that the Vertex is 1 and repeat the two steps above.

Other than this method, do we have a shortcut for finding the minimum coordinates? The book tells it is $(1,1)$, but doesn't show the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derivative is also one of tool,

$\frac{dy}{dx}=2x-2 =0$

At $x=1$:

$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = 2 >0$

We get min. At $x=1$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on all your posts. Most of them are unreadable.

Comment: Indeed difficult to read, but it's an interesting approach. We find $x=1$ but anyway to find minimum coordinates $(x,y)$ ?

Comment: for y now put x=1 in given equation

Comment: True that! Good to see this method. I like it. However, the vertex form from the completed square looks like the most straightforward method

Answer (score 0):

You can "see" the minimum from an expression like: $$(x-1)^2+1$$

Since $(x-1)^2$ is a square which is always $\ge 0$, the minimum is $1$.

---

In general for an expression like
$$a(x\pm h)^2 + k$$
the minimum is $k$ when $a\gt 0$